# A Java Plugin Framework that supports JARs

Tags: java, security, multithreading, plugins, plugin-architecture

More specifically, is there any Java plugin frameworks have all of the below features:

- Support for multiple JAR files
- JARs can be signed and/or sealed
- Can perform a license check for each JAR prior to instantiation
- Can load multiple JARs using multiple threads

Answer (score 1):

I don't happen to know of a framework that comes with built-in support for license checking JAR files (although Lotus Notes possibly might), I believe that OSGi supports the other 3 and could be made to support the 4th with some custom permission handling.  OSGi bundles are slightly different than arbitrary JARs, but the idea is pretty much equivalent.

Someone else may have a more JAR-specific suggestion.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html?page=2